# moq returns doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I try to make my simple mock to work, but it's too tedious. 
I get one mistake in this place

`(string s1, string s2) => { return (string)(s1 + s2); });`

The message says that

> "Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 2 arguments"

but in [this](http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/52/Moq-Use-Setup-arguments-parameters-in-the-Returns-of-a-mocked-function) article all works

all my code here.

```
public interface IWriteTwoString
{
    string WriteTwoStrings(string s1, string s2);
}

public MyPriceReducerTest()
{
    Mock<IWriteTwoString> writeMock = new Mock<IWriteTwoString>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    writeMock.Setup(m => m.WriteTwoStrings(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
       .Returns<string>((string s1, string s2) => { return (string)(s1 + s2); });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with the expression: `Returns<string>` which tells moq that your `WriteTwoStrings` has **one** `string` parameter, but you have **two** therefore you get an error.

So you need to write:

```
.Returns<string, string>((string s1, string s2) => { return (string)(s1 + s2); });
```

Or you can leave out the types completely because the compiler can infer them:

```
.Returns((string s1, string s2) => { return (string)(s1 + s2); });
```

Comment: You could also do `.Returns<string, string>((s1, s2) => { ... });` and let the compiler infer for the lambda. Either way works.

Comment: About last sample - i tried write Returns<string, string> - but that error is appeared again.

Comment: @user1640532 are you setting up the same method `string WriteTwoStrings(string s1, string s2)`? Because it should work with `Returns<string, string>`. You can edit and update your question with your new code if you get the same error or you can create a new question with your new problem.